# how to trigger on change event after ajax call

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker function which triggers after changing a `input[type="text"]` value. At first, please look at the html layout:

```
<input type="text" id="date_of_birth" value="" />
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1st Date</th>
            <th>2nd Date</th>
            <th>3rd Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" d="5" value="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" d="6" value="" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" d="9" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What actually happens, datepicker are attached to every `input[type="text"]`. Now when anyone change a date in `#date_of_birth` input, it will change the date of `input` fields of the following table by adding the amount of day stated in `d` attribute of those input fields of the table. It works well if I change `#date_of_birth` by selecting datepicker date manually.

But if I change the `#date_of_birth` by receiving date of birth from database (by query), then the `change` event of `#date_of_birth` is not firing, as a result date of the following tables are not changing.

```
$('body').on('click', '#selector', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url,
        data: data,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(cbdata) {
                update_table(cbdata);
            }
    });
});
```

the above `update_table(cbdata)` function inserts a date of birth to `#date_of_birth` field. But this can't trigger `change event` to that input field. Even if I add `$("#date_of_birth").change()` after the ajax call, it can't change the date of input fields of the following table.

How can I trigger change event after ajax call so that date of input fields of the following table can be changed automatically by jquery?

Comment: Provide MCVE. How do you change the date of input fields in the table??? Which datepicker plugin are you using? Etc...

Comment: And by the way, why don't you just update table value following ajax request if you already know the date updated? It really sounds like a XY problem

Comment: @A. Wollff, it is quite big chunk of code. But it brief, there is a list of users before the `date_of_birth` field which have a list of users with their userids. When someone clicks on any user's row, it triggers the ajax call which ultimately reproduce the `#date_of_birth` and the following table by the `update_table` function.

Comment: @A. Wolff, I have working code (website page), but as it is in developing stage, I can't mention it's address in public as there may be security hole in my website (I am just testing the website). I don't know how to PM in the stackoverflow.com. If you tell me to send my web address privately, I can give you the page address which is creating the problem.

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  And still, you didn't explain why can't you fill relevant inputs value with the date instead of trying to trigger an event?

Comment: If I give you page address, you can easily understand what actually happens and why.

Comment: I'm afraid but i don't debug some random website, sorry

Comment: @A. Wolff, please help me, I found your email address from your profile and send you an email mentioning my website address. Please just visit the page and review the debugging. It is not a professional webpage, it is just a personal website. So please help me in debugging.

Comment: please remove my email address (in clear) from your comment, i don't like spam bot...

Comment: Ok, done. sorry about this.

Comment: i checked it but there is too much code to debug and still not sure to get all your logic behind it. Again, you **have** to provide MCVE in order to get help on SO, otherwise go to some other website to hire a developer. I hope you understand it

Answer (score 1):

One way to trigger an event is to use the jquery trigger function.

```
$('#date_of_birth').trigger("change");
```

Comment: OP already said he tried using `$("#date_of_birth").change()`

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeDate(){
       $.ajax({
            url,
            data: data,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(cbdata) {
                    update_table(cbdata);
                }
        });
}
$('#selector').on('click', changeDate);
```

So you can call **changeData()** when you need it.

Comment: Or use `$('body').on('click', '#selector', changeDate);` anyway, with **changeData()** you don't need to trigger a change event, but just to call the function.